# Include web whatsapp own site

Tags: iframe, include, nested, whatsapp

As title, is there a possibility to include official whatsapp site on my own site with iframe or other?

Simply Iframe like this doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't.
**Explanation**:
Some sites sends "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN" response header. Which makes it imoossible to display it's content in the iframes hosted on other domain.

Using AJAX may work but will never provide the core functionality of the target webpage. It can only load little bit of html "IF" the site allows it to do so.

The other alternative known as html5 import works on same origin policy .

So reather then trying to embed whatsapp in your site, look for another options for live chatting (if that is what you are trying to achieve).